# Touch on button is not detected when a TapGestureRecognizer is attached to the container view

Tags: swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

In my app I have a viewcontroller which view has an attached tapGesture recognizer.

The tapGesture animated a hidden view (some kind of panel) which becomes visible. That view contains a button which can execute some action and then hides the panel.

But it seems like because of the tapgesture being attached to view-constroller's view, the touch on the button is not detected and only the tap on the view-controller view is fired.

I've tried playing with the firstResponder but doesn't seem to work

```
func addGesture(){
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(togglePanel))
    myView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

my panel is inseted like this:

```
 insertSubview(actionPanel, at: 0)
```

My button

```
actionPanel.addSubview(dismissBtn)
```

The button action

```
dismissBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hideActionPanel), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc func hideActionPanel(){
        print("tapped")
    }
```

Comment: can you help us help you by adding the code to your question?

Comment: @azinwi I updated my question

Comment: When did you actually run `addGesture()`?

Comment: Inside the init on my view model

Comment: @user1445685 are you disabling any user interaction in any of the views?

Comment: @GiorgioDoganiero not at all.
I tried everything I know. It seems like adding the tapGesture to the view makes it respond to all the taps on the underlying views.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to your class. To learn more go to [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate).

Then implement the `func gestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive: UITouch) -> Bool`. This function will be called every time a gesture is about to happen. If you want to know exactly how it works go here [gestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624214-gesturerecognizer).

Don't forget to connect your gesture to the delegate like this.

`tapGesture.delegate = self`

Finally, inside the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate function check if the view being touch equals to the view that has the gestureRecognizer. That will prevent any underlying views to recognize the gesture.

`if touch.view == gestureRecognizer.view {
     return true
 }
 return false`

Answer (score 0):

the button which doesn't seem to work

Run the app using xcode, Use Xcode "Debug View Hierarchy"

this button or it's superview may be `.userInteractionEnabled = false`

I assume that your animated image is a superview, and the image turns off user interaction by default

add this `xxImage.userInteractionEnabled = true`